# Tensorflow - Multi-GPU doesn’t work for model(inputs) nor when computing the gradients

Tags: tensorflow, keras, multi-gpu

When using multiple GPUs to perform inference on a model (e.g. the call method: model(inputs)) and calculate its gradients, the machine only uses one GPU, leaving the rest idle.

For example in this code snippet below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0,1"

# Make the tf-data
path_filename_records = 'your_path_to_records'
bs = 128

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(path_filename_records)
dataset = (dataset
           .map(parse_record, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
           .batch(bs)
           .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
          )

# Load model trained using MirroredStrategy
path_to_resnet = 'your_path_to_resnet'
mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with mirrored_strategy.scope():
    resnet50 = tf.keras.models.load_model(path_to_resnet)

for pre_images, true_label in dataset:
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
       tape.watch(pre_images)
       outputs = resnet50(pre_images)
       grads = tape.gradient(outputs, pre_images)
```

Only one GPU is used. You can profile the behavior of the GPUs with nvidia-smi. I don't know if it is supposed to be like this, both the `model(inputs)` and `tape.gradient` to not have multi-GPU support. But if it is, then it's a big problem because if you have a large dataset and need to calculate the gradients with respect to the inputs (e.g. interpretability porpuses) it might take days with one GPU.
Another thing I tried was using `model.predict()` but this isn't possible with `tf.GradientTape`.

**What I've tried so far and didn't work**

1. Put all the code inside mirrored strategy scope.
2. Used different GPUs: I've tried A100, A6000 and RTX5000. Also changed the number of graphic cards and varied the batch size.
3. Specified a list of GPUs, for instance, `strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(['/gpu:0', '/gpu:1'])`.
4. Added this `strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(cross_device_ops=tf.distribute.HierarchicalCopyAllReduce())` as @Kaveh suggested.

**How do I know that only one GPU is working?**

I used the command `watch -n 1 nvidia-smi` in the terminal and observed that only one GPU is at 100%, the rest are at 0%.

**Working Example**

You can find a working example with a CNN trained on the dogs_vs_cats datasets below. You won't need to manually download the dataset as I used the tfds version, nor train a model.

**Notebook**: [Working Example.ipynb](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CoYVckmEQXp2Wf_PRlGtnrlGnF8smxvt/view?usp=sharing)

**Saved Model**:

- [HDF5](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y0-fQytVsnHPs8JL6kKJr3tEL0mKNtjJ/view?usp=sharing)
- [Saved Format](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19oSIaUTtEy1q6rlDj8GzuWIvwAq_7XMi/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: you probably need ton put all your code inside the mirrored strategy scope, right now only the model loading is inside scope.

Comment: Hi @Dr.Snoopy, I did try that but the same behavior persisted.

Comment: How do you determine that one GPU is being used?

Comment: os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0, 1", I am using two A100s and I check nvidia-smi

Comment: One is at 100% and the other is at 0%

Comment: This `strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(cross_device_ops=tf.distribute.HierarchicalCopyAllReduce())` may resolve your issue.

Comment: Just tried it, no bueno :( 
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Have you tried to list gpus in your defiition? like this: `strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(["GPU:0", "GPU:1"])`.

Comment: Yes sir! I will update my question with all of those details that both of you pointed out.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?
Right now when trying to reproduce the behaviour, I have the 2 GPUs used.
In any cas you might want to look into: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/MirroredStrategy#run

Comment: Another problem might be that when specifying the visible devices you need to avoid commas. I haven't tested this because I don't have access right now to 2 physical GPUs, but it rings a bell. See https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#env-vars

Comment: Hi @ZaccharieRamzi. Thank you for your help! I will edit the question and add an example. Nevertheless, I have a couple of questions regarding your statement.

1. Can you actually give me a working example of this working? Does it actually compute the gradients when you use the run method? Can you print the result and check that the gradients are not None?

2. I don't understand your last comment. What do you mean by avoiding commas? Do you mean spaces between the numbers and the commas? Can't really find that in the link that you provided.

Cheers.

Comment: Re #2 yes sorry I meant avoid spaces.
Re #1 I will come back to you shortly with a colab illustrating what I tried, but working on your minimal example might be best

Comment: Thank you. I agree, working on a minimal example is best. I will provide it ASAP. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: You can find the colab illustrating what I tried here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jld4hhq0VNiWyzk1UPjLhp6kA5oPrMA0?usp=sharing
I use weights and biases to monitor the gpu usage as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62654077/4332585)
Because I am on colab, I have only one physical GPU and I therefore created 2 logical GPUs. Therefore when monitoring, a use of more than 50% (compute or memory) indicates that the distribution worked.
The `grads` are not `None`.

Comment: Hi @ZaccharieRamzi, sorry for the late reply. I've added a working example in the description. Also, I tried what you suggested. I don't think the example that you provide is too farfetched from the one that I gave in the code snippet. The problem remains the same :/

Comment: First, try to print number of GPUs 
`strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy() `
`print('Number of devices: {}'.format(strategy.num_replicas_in_sync))`

Comment: Try setting up these two
`os.environ["NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] ="0,1"`
`os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0,1"`

Comment: Hi @Aravinda_gn, thank you very much for your help! Regarding the first comment, I did that in the working example. That prints 2. About the last statement, just tried it and the issue still remains :/

Comment: Did u try updating GPU driver, CUDA, TensorFlow version? @mCalado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **supposed** to run in single gpu (probably the first gpu, `GPU:0`) for any codes that are outside of `mirrored_strategy.run()`. Also, as you want to have the gradients returned from replicas, `mirrored_strategy.gather()` is needed as well.

Besides these, a distributed dataset must be created by using `mirrored_strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset`. Distributed dataset tries to distribute single batch of data across replicas evenly. An example about these points is included below.

`model.fit()`, `model.predict()`,and etc... run in distributed manner automatically just because they've already handled everything mentioned above for you.

Example codes:

```
mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
print(f'using distribution strategy\nnumber of gpus:{mirrored_strategy.num_replicas_in_sync}')

dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.rand(64,224,224,3)).batch(8)

#create distributed dataset
ds = mirrored_strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(dataset)

#make variables mirrored
with mirrored_strategy.scope():
  resnet50=tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50()

def step_fn(pre_images):
  with tf.GradientTape(watch_accessed_variables=False) as tape:
       tape.watch(pre_images)
       outputs = resnet50(pre_images)[:,0:1]
  return tf.squeeze(tape.batch_jacobian(outputs, pre_images))

#define distributed step function using strategy.run and strategy.gather
@tf.function
def distributed_step_fn(pre_images):
  per_replica_grads = mirrored_strategy.run(step_fn, args=(pre_images,))
  return mirrored_strategy.gather(per_replica_grads,0)

#loop over distributed dataset with distributed_step_fn
for result in map(distributed_step_fn,ds):
  print(result.numpy().shape)
```

Comment: Hi @Laplace Ricky, thanks a lot for your help. I just tried it and this seems to work! Congratulations! I have had this problem for a very long time and can't thank you enough!

Comment: I have some questions about your answer: 
1. What does ``tf.squeeze(tape.batch_jacobian(outputs, pre_images))`` do and why didn't you use the tape.gradients? I tried with the ``tape.gradient`` and it works!
2. What is the second parameter in ``mirrored_strategy.gather(per_replica_grads,0)`` and why zero?

Comment: Since the bounty is expiring and the solution works, I am giving you the reward. Nevertheless, I would like to work on the answer a little bit more.

Comment: Replies to your questions, 1. I am just giving an arbitrary example here as I don't know what gradients you want. My example computes the gradients of the first output(among 1000 outputs from resnet50) with respect to inputs. Regarding `tape.gradient`, we usually pass a scalar to its first argument for the sake of clarity, but if you think that it's giving the gradients you want, just go ahead. 2. as the distributed dataset divides the input data to replicas along the first dimension, `mirrored_strategy.gather` joins the output data back along the first dimension.