# How to use GPU when transcribing using deepspeech

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, transcription, mozilla-deepspeech

I'm using the excellent [deepspeech](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech) package to transcribe an audio file in Python. Here's my quick implementation:

```
import wave
import deepspeech
import numpy as np

model_file_path = 'deepspeech-0.9.3-models.pbmm'
model = deepspeech.Model(model_file_path)
filename = 'podcast.wav'
w = wave.open(filename, 'r')
frames = w.getnframes()
buffer = w.readframes(frames)
data16 = np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype=np.int16)
text = model.stt(data16)
```

`podcast.wav` is a ~20 minute audio file. Running `text = model.stt(data16)` takes 10+ minutes (I interrupted the process after 10 minutes), which is unexpectedly slow given the availability of a GPU (I'm using Google Colab). I suspect that the script isn't using the GPU. **Is there another implementation of the above code to ensure the use of a GPU?** I can confirm that `deepspeech-gpu` is installed.

Answer (score 2):

Having **only** deepspeech-gpu installed should do it.

`pip install deepspeech-gpu`

Try uninstalling the CPU version that you might have previously installed.

`pip uninstall deepspeech`

You can verify this by monitoring your GPU usage.
[Display GPU Usage While Code is Running in Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620268/display-gpu-usage-while-code-is-running-in-colab)